# windowless wpf application example?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windowless

Any advice or links or sample application (for VS2010) re how to develop a "windowless" WPF application?

That is the ones that look quite modern and don't seem to have the historical window chrome around the edges - they seem to have rounded edges etc...

Comment: Do you me applications like thirteen23's Blu?

Comment: @Avatar - yes (just had a look) - this is the type of thing I'm asking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a project that did exactly what you are talking about, we used the following project from Microsoft,
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell
Initially I tried writing it myself by turning off the chrome, not a good idea unless you don't want to be able to drag your window around in the standard windows method.

Comment: thanks Josh - looks like it quite a tricky thing to do then no?  I'm getting the feeling that unless you're really ready to roll your sleeves up and spend some time in this area you might be better off not trying to alter the standard windows chrome you get?  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: With Microsofts WPFShell project it is not hard at all, I have examples if you need them. But in terms of completely writing it yourself (without WPFShell), yes it is very detailed, the part where I gave up is being able to dock windows in Windows 7, I guess you need to write a lot of interop to make that work properly.

Comment: do you think projects like thirteen23's Blu (as Avatar mentioned) would have used WPFShell?  Or I guess what I'm wondering to what extent most people are using the WPFShell project for doing this kind of thing?

Comment: We are using it in a commercial financial application, it gives a very custom look. Blu in particular would be reasonably easy with WPFShell. When I attempted this type of thing manually I discovered performance issues with "AllowTransparency" set to true, but seems WPFShell is doing another method, as I didn't run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove StartupUri and in the Application Startup method dont load a window:

public partial class App

{

```
    public static bool IsTrue ;

    public App()
    {
        Startup += AppStartup;
    }


    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Trace.WriteLine("blah");
        }
        IsTrue = false;

    }
    void AppStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IsTrue = true;
        new Thread(DoWork).Start();
        while (IsTrue)
        { }
        Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

}